Duplication ML.NET example/Tutorial movie recommender using matrix factorization
I'm new to machine learning, but I have experience in C#, which is why I want to pick up Ml.net to familiarize myself with the topic.
As I grasp the concept, I have decided to make a movie recommendation model that will take previous reviews and recommend a movie with the same example as available on Microsoft ML.NET tutorials.
My issue is that when I build and train a model in the function below while creating a pipeline, I don't see a method call of Recommendation(). By the way, I am using VS2022 and .NET 8.0. Can anyone suggest why?
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms;

ITransformer BuildAndTrainModel(MLContext mlContext, IDataView trainingDataView)
{
    //STEP 3: Transform your data by encoding the two features userId and movieID. These encoded features will be provided as input
    //        to our MatrixFactorizationTrainer.
    var dataProcessingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "userIdEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(MovieRating.userId))
                   .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "movieIdEncoded", inputColumnName: nameof(MovieRating.movieId)));

    //Specify the options for MatrixFactorization trainer            
    MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options options = new MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options();
    options.MatrixColumnIndexColumnName = "userIdEncoded";
    options.MatrixRowIndexColumnName = "movieIdEncoded";
    options.LabelColumnName = "Label";
    options.NumberOfIterations = 20;
    options.ApproximationRank = 100;

    //STEP 4: Create the training pipeline 
    var trainingPipeLine = dataProcessingPipeline.Append(mlContext.Recommendation().Transforms.MatrixFactorization(options));

   

    Console.WriteLine("=============== Training the model ===============");
    ITransformer model = trainingPipeLine.Fit(trainingDataView);

    return model;
}


I did a few searches in Github code, but I am getting no pointers.

How do you know the object can be able to use method Recommendation? I don't see it in the source definition code.  Take a look at my answer. :)

Because there doesn't have such method definition:
Microsoft.ML.MLContext Class
